# Ubuntu 20.04 screen freeze. When I am in the list of programs, and I ungroup one or more programs from a group to individualize them

Tags: screen, lock-screen

[image]

Steps to make the screen freeze

1. I turn on my laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 operating system (I recently installed it)
2. I enter my password and login
3. I click on the icon of nine small white squares (Located in the lower left corner of the screen)
   4.Once I do that I find myself in the panel with a set of icons (Programs) such as help (blue circle icon with a question mark) etc.
4. I group several programs (whatever they may be) into the same group, such as the group of programs called "Utilities" (in which disks, terminal, etc.)
   6.Then I enter the previously created group and start taking program by program to leave it individually (Of course, do it quickly)
5. When this operation is being performed is when (at any time) the frozen screen occurs.

[image]

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. Please edit your question and include a clear description of the problem. You should also describe, unambiguously, the steps needed to reproduce the problem.  It's important to be specific instead of generic, so we can understand your query. For example, instead of "several applications", list the applications. It also looks like you tried to attach an image, but it's not there.  Please edit your question.